# Connect to Telnet client via COM port

Tags: serial-port, port, telnet, ethernet, forwarding

I am connected to a remote machine via Telnet (Ethernet connected). On the remote machine I am running a diagnostic command that sends periodical output to my Telnet session on the local machine (windows7). Now, this output received by Telnet needs to be fed into another application on my local machine. So far, so good.

My problem is now, that this application is expecting the input from COM port only. I am looking for a solution to somehow forward the Telnet output into my application via a virtual COM port.

A plus would be to have the connection bidirectional but this is optional. Most important is to have the Telnet output on the virtual COM. So it can be read by the application.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your telnet client would require some kind of external logging (like e.g. putty does). That log you could then `tail` into the serial port.